# How do you pass a generic delegate argument to a method in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, delegates

I have a class with a delegate declaration as follows...

```
Public Class MyClass  
    Public Delegate Function Getter(Of TResult)() As TResult    

    ''#the following code works.
    Public Shared Sub MyMethod(ByVal g As Getter(Of Boolean))
        ''#do stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, I do not want to explicitly type the Getter delegate in the Method call.  Why can I not declare the parameter as follows...

```
... (ByVal g As Getter(Of TResult))
```

Is there a way to do it?

My end goal was to be able to set a delegate for property setters and getters in the called class.  But my reading indicates you can't do that.  So I put setter and getter methods in that class and then I want the calling class to set the delegate argument and then invoke.  Is there a best practice for doing this.

I realize in the above example that I can set set the delegate variable from the calling class...but I am trying to create a singleton with tight encapsulation.

For the record, I can't use any of the new delegate types declared in .net35.

Answers in C# are welcome.

Any thoughts?

Seth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a generic type parameter to the method:

```
Public Shared Sub MyMethod(Of TResult) (ByVal g As Getter(Of TResult))
```

In C#, that would be

```
public static void MyMethod<TResult>(Getter<TResult> g) {
```

Comment: You could also make the whole class generic

Comment: @Joel: That violates FxCop guidelines and has subtle and unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the method that accepts the generic delegate itself generic:

```
Public Shared Sub MyMethod(Of TResult)(ByVal g As Getter(Of TResult))
    'do stuff
End Sub
```